# Weblogic 10.3.6 jars, unable to find ContextElementDictionary.SAML_ATTRIBUTE_PRINCIPALS

Tags: weblogic, saml

In the project I'm working on we have a custom Identity Asserter Attribute Mapper class that implements the `SAMLIdentityAssertionAttributeMapper`interface. The class implements the method `mapAttributeInfo`.

The documentation states the following:

"void mapAttributeInfo(Collection attrStmtInfos,
                      ContextHandler contextHandler)

map from collection of SAMLAttributeStatementInfo to collection of Principal. The implementation of this interface is expected to add the collection of Principal to the context handler under name ContextElementDictionary.SAML_ATTRIBUTE_PRINCIPALS" (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13941/weblogic/security/providers/saml/SAMLIdentityAssertionAttributeMapper.html)

When the project was running on WebLogic 10.3.2 this line was working perfectly:

```
((SecurityTokenContextHandler)contextHandler).addContextElement(ContextElementDictionary.SAML_ATTRIBUTE_PRINCIPALS, principals);
```

Now that the project is supposed to run on WebLogic 10.3.6, and using the 10.3.6 jars, I'm unable to find a jar that contains `ContextElementDictionary.SAML_ATTRIBUTE_PRINCIPALS`. Unfortunately, when googling `ContextElementDictionary` I'm unable to find a solution in any of the 8 search results.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment but too long to post as such...

ContextElementDictionary exists in the default weblogic.jar file. See the following results:

```
jar -tf /opt/ora/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar | grep ContextElementD

weblogic/security/utils/ContextElementDictionary.class
```

However, that class does not appear to contain ContextElementDictionary.SAML_ATTRIBUTE_PRINCIPALS when I do a:

```
strings weblogic/security/utils/ContextElementDictionary.class
```

Maybe compare those two jar files and those two classes to see if something changed.

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem that I was having. For 10.3.2 the class could be found in this package: `com.bea.common.security.utils.ContextElementDictionary`. For 10.3.6 I found it here: `weblogic.security.utils.ContextElementDictionary`